# git remote update not working

Tags: linux, git, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote

RHEL Server 8 logged in as user with root access.
I have a private mirror of a public repo that is on github. The private mirror is being used as a git server repo locally. I'm trying to update the private mirror. I would really appreciate knowing why this is not working. I'm unable to get the latest code from github. My client is only seeing the branch dev as it was last week.

```
sudo -u apache bash
bash-4.4$ git remote update
Fetching origin
From https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework
 * branch              HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
bash-4.4$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework.git
  HEAD branch: dev
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev             pushes to dev             (local out of date)
    master          pushes to master          (local out of date)
    revert-1603-dev pushes to revert-1603-dev (up to date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally resolved it. This is by no means a complete and comprehensive answer but thought I would share my solution. In my case when I first cloned the source repository apparently I used `git clone --bare ...` instead of `git clone --mirror ...`. The net result was a local config file that looked like this:

```
$ cd test_repo.git
$ cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://example.com/test_repo.git
```

Using `git clone --mirror ...` the config file looks like this and `git remote update` works now.

```
$ cd test_repo.git
$ cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://example.com/test_repo.git
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
```